# Where does the cancellation token come from in a background worker?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am using a background and but default I have this 2 methods:

```
public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
}

public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
}
```

I have another method that do something and if there is some error, I would like to stop the service.

```
private MyMethod()
{
    //do something
    if(some error)
    {
         StopAsync(???)
    }
}
```

But My doubt is which cancellation token I have to use as parameter, because I don't know when is called the StartAsync() and StopAsync() methods, and I don't know if the cancellation token is the same object when they are called or they are different objects.

If it is the same method, where could I find this method to use as parameter when I try to call the StopAsync() method?

In summary, I would like to know which is the best way to stop the service if something is wrong and I decide to stop it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use the Start and Stop methods?  You can instead inherit from `BackgroundService` and override `ExecuteAsync()`.  Either way the token is created and passed by the host; you don't do this explicitly.  If you want to cancel before the token is cancelled, you can use whatever signalling mechanism you want and just return from `ExecuteAsync()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancellation token is there to cancel only async operation (`Task`). Nothing more to that.

So, if you want to be able to cancel started operation, let's say `StopAsync` you just create `CancellationTokenSource` and pass it's property `Token` to a method and in case cancellation of that operation is needed, you just call `Cancel` method, which would cancel the `StopAsync`. It's just about cancelling particular operations.

If you do not want to have this possibility, just pass `default` there :)